# Cruise Control fails with VaultVersionChecker: CheckForModifications. Could be repository path spaces

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I'm putting a project under cruise control .net. I am using CCNet version  1.8.2.0 which is the latest. The project keeps breaking with the error

```
Failing Tasks : VaultVersionChecker: CheckForModifications
```

Digging deeper cruise control is trying to execute the command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\SourceGear\Vault Client\vault.exe 
versionhistory $/projects/Project Name/Project -rowlimit 1 
-host myhost -user myuser -password ***** -repository "MyRepository"
```

This fails if run directly on the command line but if I change it to wrap the repository in apostrophes then it can be executed directly on the command line i.e.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\SourceGear\Vault Client\vault.exe 
versionhistory "$/projects/Project Name/Project" -rowlimit 1 
-host myhost -user myuser -password ***** -repository "MyRepository"
```

So - cruise control appears to be failing because my repository folder has a space i.e.

```
$/projects/Project Name/Project
```

I'm not willing to change the folders within vault to get cruise control working. Strangely this setup has worked before perfectly well in a previous version of cruise control.

My config for this project is

```
<project>
    <name>NRE Test</name>
    <!-- Get latest from Vault -->
    <sourcecontrol type="vault" autoGetSource="true" applyLabel="false">
      <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\SourceGear\Vault Client\vault.exe</executable>
      <username>myuser</username>
      <password>mypassword</password>
      <host>myhost</host>
      <repository>MyRepository</repository>
      <folder>$/projects/Project Name/Project</folder>
      <ssl>false</ssl>
      <cleanCopy>true</cleanCopy>
      <timeout units="minutes">10</timeout>
      <useWorkingDirectory>false</useWorkingDirectory>
      <workingDirectory>C:\Program Files (x86)\CI\CruiseControl.NET\Projects\Project</workingDirectory>
    </sourcecontrol>
    <tasks>
<!-- More tasks -->
    </tasks>
  </project>
```

So - am I right about the apostrophes being the issue here? How can I get round this? Am I missing another issue.

Many Thanks for all help

Comment: Your command line examples are the same. Assume it is supposed to be `versionhistory $/projects/Project Name/Project -rowlimit 1` in the first example

Comment: @TheChairman. Your right. I've amended the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess but have you tried this:

```
<sourcecontrol type="vault" autoGetSource="true" applyLabel="false">
  <!-- ... -->
  <folder>"$/projects/Project Name/Project"</folder>
  <!-- ... -->
</sourcecontrol>
```

Comment: That works! Don't know why I didn't try that one. Actually in previous versions of CC this is not needed so I think it's a bug in the latest build TBH